Why does Python's multiprocess use all cores if I am telling it not to?
I am running a script that includes
import multiprocess as mp

def sample():
   # ... do things...
   return x

num_cores = 50
num_samples = 1000
with mp.Pool(num_cores) as p:
    samples = p.starmap(self, [() for i in range(num_samples)])

There are 128 cores in my server. However, even though I create a pool with just 50 of them, when I run htop in the terminal I see that all 128 cores are being used by my script, and each at 100% usage.
Why is this happening? I thought only num_cores cores could be used my script. Or does this depend on what sample() is actually doing?

Yes, it depends on what sample() is actually doing. If you call a function that does its own parallelization, it'll use as many cores as it uses, no matter whether multiprocessing is in play or not; when you set up a pool you tell the pool how many jobs it can run at a time, not how many cores it can use.

(indeed, if you check the multiprocessing docs, the argument is not called num_cores but processes, which better describes its actual effect; likewise, the doc describes it as "number of processes to use", not number of cores).

@CharlesDuffy That makes sense. I had a complete misunderstanding of how multiprocessing works. Your comment answers my question, so even if maybe it is too basic, if you want to post it as an answer I can accept it just in case someone else gets confused as me and comes here looking for an answer.

The argument to mp.Pool tells it how many processes, at most, to run at a time; it does not constrain how many cores those processes use.
If each process uses more than one core (whether by multithreading, or starting more subprocesses of its own, or otherwise), a multiprocessing pool can easily use more cores than the number of concurrent processes it's told to invoke.
